Looking for feedback on the improvement of this code
This code works, but it uses "Select" and is slow.  I'm looking for feedback on how to avoid using "Select" and maybe speed up the execution.
Sub getcellvalue()

Dim Man_Rows As Integer
Man_Rows = Sheets("Managers").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim Man_Name As Variant
Dim Man_cell As Variant
    
    For Each Man_cell In Sheets("Managers").Range("A1:A" & Man_Rows)
   
    Man_Name = Man_cell.Value
    
    Sheets("Home").Select
    Sheets("Home").Range("$A$21:$R$62585").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Man_Name
    Sheets("Home").Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(Man_Name).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    
    Next Man_cell
    
    
End Sub

The Home tab contains all of the data.  The Managers tab is a list of Managers extracted from the Home tab.  The code filters the Home tab for each Manager and copies the results to the corresponding manager tab. It works but I'm sure could be more efficient.
thanks

You could use the Filter function on each sheet, no VBA code needed at all.

A first step to improve the code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/6600940

In general non-working code: Stack Overflow, working code: Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic


Select is not necessary in most case. Pls read the post on @Storax's comment.

Note: Assuming the sheet named after the manager exists; otherwise, additional code will be needed.


Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.ShowAllData method (Excel)


Worksheet.ShowAllData method (Excel)


Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)

Sub getcellvalue()
    Dim Man_Rows As Long
    Man_Rows = Sheets("Managers").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Man_Name As String
    Dim Man_cell As Range
    Dim rngData As Range, rngVis As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    With Sheets("Home")
        Set rngData = .Range("$A$21:$R$62585")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
    End With
    For Each Man_cell In Sheets("Managers").Range("A1:A" & Man_Rows)
        Man_Name = Man_cell.Value
        With Sheets(Man_Name)
            Set rngCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            If rngCell.Row = 2 And Len(.Cells(1, 1)) = 0 Then Set rngCell = .Cells(1, 1)
        End With
        rngData.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Man_Name
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngVis = rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then
            rngVis.Copy rngCell
        End If
    Next Man_cell
    Sheets("Home").ShowAllData
End Sub

